# What is the origin of "Krokodili"?

Tags: etymology

It seems that *krokodili* means when two Esperantists speak with each other in a language other than Esperanto, what is the origin of this use?

Comment: It is ironic that we are discussing this in English!

Comment: we used to make the distinction between using your native language, which was called "krokodili" and using a different non-native language (eg english) which we called "aligatori" (turns out that there is a whole list of terms:  https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reptiliumi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wiktionary offers several possibilities:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/krokodili#Etymology

including

"From crocodile tears. A crocodile sheds tears while eating its prey. The *krokodilanto* bemoans the fate of Esperanto while not bothering to speak it."

Answer (score 5):

I heard that people say it because crocodiles have big mouths and small brains, ie, they talk a lot (big mouth) without thinking (small brain). However it is not mentioned in the Wikipedia article so I don't know if this is the true origin. I think it's an amusing analogy nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

There are some rather persistent stories about an Esperanto instructor who had a crocodile hand puppet.  Supposedly he used it when he would occasionally answer a question from a beginner in their native language rather than in Esperanto.  Thus, only the *krokodilo* spoke in any language other than Esperanto.

Comment: The wikidictionary entry perhaps mentions a version of this: "When [Andreo Cseh] taught Esperanto, students were only allowed to speak their native language when they were holding a wooden crocodile he always brought with him" but suggests this was a reference to the expression rather than the origin of it.